# JavaScript .click function not working inside $(document).ready tags{}

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, document-ready

Right so I am developing a project and have encountered an issue.
Please note I am still developing my skills in JavaScript effective programming :)

## Aim

I'm trying to pass the clicked link to a variable called **currentNavElement**, which then is used to determine the offset using `$(currentNavElement).offset()`.
The result is stored in a var called **navPosition**. **navPosition** then is used to determine the positioning and cannot have CSS property top : 0. **navBorder** is a variable used to animate the nav-border's top CSS property based on the offset of **currentNavElement**.

## What I'm doing

I wrap my functions around with `$(document).ready(function() {` to initiate the functions inside, but the Click function inside **Setup** isn't working for some reason (or not passed on to the global variable)

## Edited Code - Called animateBorder as suggested by @Mark_M

```
var currentNavElement;

setup: $(document).ready(function() {
    /* Am I calling animateBorder right? */
    $(".nav-element a").click(function(animateBorder) {
        currentNavElement = $(this).parent(".nav-element");
    })
})

animateBorder: $(document).ready(function() {
    var navPosition = $(currentNavElement).offset() , 
        navBorder = !!(navPosition && navPosition.top >= 0) && navPosition.top;

    if (!1 === navBorder) return !1;
    $("#nav-border").css('top', navBorder)

})
```

## JavaScript Code with error

```
var currentNavElement;

setup: $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav-element a").click(function() {
        currentNavElement = $(this).parent(".nav-element");
    })
})

animateBorder: $(document).ready(function() {
    var navPosition = $(currentNavElement).offset() , 
        navBorder = !!(navPosition && navPosition.top >= 0) && navPosition.top;

    if (!1 === navBorder) return !1;
    $("#nav-border").css('top', navBorder)

})
```

The below code works (but without $(this) click recognition thats passed on to the variable). Instead, I define the first nav link by `.nav-element a`.

## JavaScript Code that works

```
var currentNavElement;

setup: $(document).ready(function() {
        currentNavElement = $(".nav-element a").parent(".nav-element");
})

animateBorder: $(document).ready(function() {
    var navPosition = $(currentNavElement).offset() , 
        navBorder = !!(navPosition && navPosition.top >= 0) && navPosition.top;

    if (!1 === navBorder) return !1;
    $("#nav-border").css('top', navBorder)

})
```

Is it an issue with my global variable, ready function or how it's accessed?

Thank you in advanace

Comment: Your animate code is called once before any click has set `currentNavElement`. You need to call the animate code on click as well if you want it to animate on click.

Comment: @Mark_M Alright I tried to edit the script and call animateBorder in the click event, to no avail. `$(".nav-element a").click(function(animateBorder) {`

Check edited post to see how I did it . Thanks :)

Comment: @Mark_M still didnt resolve the issue. Is it called right? Thanks

Comment: Your code is still pretty mixed up. See the answer for an idea on how to get it working..

Answer (score 0):

You should define **functions** which you can then call. I'm not sure where you saw the syntax with the colons, but it's not what you want here. To define a function use:

```
function functionName(arguments) {
   // function body
}
```

To use the function, you call it:

```
functionName(arguments)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the code, but here's one way to wire up a working version of the clicks/animate functions:

```js
var currentNavElement;

// function to handle clicks
function handleCLick(e) {
  currentNavElement = $(this).parent(".nav-element");
  // now call animate border
  animateBorder()
}
// function to move element
function animateBorder() {
  var navPosition = $(currentNavElement).offset()
  var  navBorder = (navPosition && navPosition.top >= 0) && navPosition.top;
  if (navBorder) $("#nav-border").css('top', navBorder)
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  // pass the click handler to click()
  $(".nav-element a").click(handleCLick)
})
```

```css
.nav-element {
  top: 20px;
  /*display: inline-block*/
}

#nav-border {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 20px;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav-border">
  <p class="nav-element">
    <a href="#">click me</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mark_M. I can indeed get the border to slide - One issue im facing is, I want the border to go into position in the appropriate section (according to nav element a), on page reload.

It activates on click as intended, but stays ontop on page reload as you can see here -  [My site nav border](https://gyazo.com/c615f4d5736651c6f4e47337836df43a).

Imagine like an :active color change for an icon if the section is displayed. Instead I want the border to slide initially.

Many thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a new question @Sam_M — I think basically you'll need to look at the page's url and use that to decide where the border should go.